# white material on roots of apple tree?

Tags: trees, diseases

When I dug up a young apple tree to move it to a sunnier location, I noticed some sort of white material on the roots.  Is this cause for concern?

Comment: I've seen quite a few white thing on apple tree roots - some damaging, some neutral. can you post a picture?

Comment: Unfortunately, I replanted it. Hopefully it is mycorrhiza

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the tree is perfectly healthy and is growing well, the mycorrhiza is most likely beneficial. It might mean the soil was a bit dry - this seems to make the mycorrhiza more visible, but in the main, mycorrhiza is usually present and there is a beneficial synergistic exchange between the plant and the fungi.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's [mycorrhiza](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycorrhiza)? If so... No.